# Static chains and binding

Tags: language-agnostic, scope

I'm confused about how binding works for statically scoped variables in nested subroutines.

```
proc A:
      var a, x
       ...
          proc B:
                var x, y
                  ...
                proc B2:
                      var a, b
                      ...
                end B2
          end B
                   proc C:
                     var x, z, w
                         ....
                     end C
end A
```

First, this is what I have understood: if static scoping is considered, then B2 can use the variable x and y present in its parent B. Similarly C can use the variable a used in proc A.

Now, my questions are: are these bindings made during the compile-time or run-time?  Does it make a difference if the variables are statically scoped or dynamically scoped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until it comes naturally, I find it easy to draw environment model diagrams. They are also pretty much essential for exams and those esoteric examples that are intended to be confusing. I suggest the famous SICP (http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), but there are obviously more than enough resources on the internet (a quick google brought me to this: http://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/~gelbart/cs61a/EnvDiagrams.pdf).

It depends on the language/implementation when/how bindings are done, however in your example the bindings can be done at compile time. In general, static scoping, as the name suggests allows for a lot of static/compile-time binding. A compiler can look into a function and see all references and resolve them immediately. For example in `B2`, a reference to `y` can be resolved immediately to belong to the enclosing scope, i.e. that of `B`.

As per dynamic vs. static scoping, there is a **huge** difference. Dynamic, as the name suggests, is much harder to do compile-time bindings with, since the structure of the code does not define the references to the variables. Different paths of execution may yield different bindings. You'll have to be more specific with the question though.

Comment: Thanks @davin.  That answers my question to a certain extent.  Now I understand that the compiler looks at the program and can resolve the references.  What I still do not understand is how are these bindings maintained?  I would think that (in case of static scoping), these bindings would be maintained using static links/chains, but are these chains not made during run-time?  And if so, how are the bindings made during compile-time?

Comment: @Shobit, aahh, how they're maintained is much more dependant on the implementation. The most basic and unoptimised way is to maintain each scope as an environment record with a variable lookup table, and store the entire program as one large tree of records, nested according to scope nesting. There is a great section in the book I mentioned where they actually build a language evaluator and if you look there you can see precisely how they do it: http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1

Comment: @Shobit, that doesn't involve any optimisations and indeed a lot of work will be done at run-time. However it is not difficult to see that optimisations could be done at compile-time; a compiler could analyse certain code and restructure it to make, for example, variable lookup faster. Let's say I have a loop that is deeply nested in scopes, that at each iteration references a variable that is in an outer scope. Each iteration I will have to search for the variable in the local scope, and then the outer scope, etc. until we arrive at the outermost scope where the variable belongs.

Comment: @Shobit, A compiler can recognise this situation, and add an entry into the *nested* environment record that merely points to the location of the actual variable - since it resolved this at *compile-time*. Then, at run-time, the lookup will find the variable in the inner-most scope and immediately jump to the right place. It's easy to see how that can be done at compile-time and optimises lookup.